# How to print the value from the drop down box in flask?

Tags: python, flask

This my base HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>names</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>PS: <a href="/ps">Home</a></div>
    <hr>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

This my tasks.html file

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="page">
  <table>
  <tr>
  <form action="{{ url_for('new_task') }}" method="POST" class=new-task>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <label>name :</label>
  <select name="name" width="100px">
  <option value="1">name1</option>
  <option value="2">name2</option>
  <option value="3">name3</option>
  <option value="4">name4</option>
  <option value="5">name5</option>
  </select>
  </td>
  <td>
  &nbsp;
  &nbsp;
  <input class="button1" type="submit" value="Press">
  </td>
  </form>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   </table>
{% endblock %}
```

This my python file views.py

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
@app.route('/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def new_task():
    tts = request.form['name']
    flash(str(tts)+'is being selected')
    render_template("tasks.html")
@app.route('/ps')
def ps():
    render_template("ps.html")
```

I want to just print the value whatever is being selected from the drop down menu.
But i am getting this error
 "Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL."
Actually i am new to flask programming
Please tell me where i am doing wrong . Help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong @app.route('/tasks', methods=['POST']) means that it will set a path to the html file

Comment: new_task() function will be called whenever a request comes to '/tasks'.

Comment: \microblog .....run.py \app ......views.py \templates .....tasks.html .....ps.html . I tried with  @app.route('/', methods=['POST']), now it give this error NameError: global name 'flash' is not defined

Comment: You haven't imported flash, add from flask import flash

Comment: yes it working now but when i am pressing the Press button it is giving "ValueError: View function did not return a response" error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually method not allowed has to do with form methods of GET/POST etc. I would suggest a few changes.

**template**:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('new_task') }}" method="POST" class=new-task>
```

**View**:

```
@app.route('/tasks/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def new_task():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tts = request.form['name']
        flash(str(tts)+'is being selected')
    return render_template("tasks.html")
```

Comment: This is the error i am getting.
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: How are you accessing the URL ? Make sure you are entering /tasks and no trailing / at the end since you don't have it in the view. If you try as /tasks/, it won't work.

Comment: @Parakrant: codegeek is correct. Add trailing '/' to app.route as @app.route('/tasks/', methods=['GET','POST']) and also added 'GET' to methods list. If you access through URL, it will become GET request and will throw error "Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL"

Comment: NameError: global name 'request' is not defined  now this is the error when i changed this  @app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

Comment: @Parakrant: Add "from flask import request". app route should be @app.route('/tasks/', methods=['GET','POST']) as mentioned by codegeek

Comment: My whole directory structure is                                    \microblog
  run.py
  \app
    views.py
    \templates
      tasks.html 
       ps.html                                                      The tasks.html is present in the app/templates/ directory. The run.py is present in the microblog directory. May my path name is not proper. please suggest

Comment: @codegeek Hello, I have a similar question. Mind helping me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628274/unable-to-get-value-selected-in-python-from-a-dropdown-using-flask

Comment: It should be  tts = request.form['name'] instead of  tts = request.form['tts']