# Flask: How to run a function with a post method as a background task and then access it in another class

Tags: python, post, flask

I'm automating a pump which is turned on only when the soil humidity value(obtained from a soil humidity sensor) exceeds a certain value. This is how it is:

1. A user selects a value from a dropdown (threshold value for the soil humidity)
2. The python script continuously checks if the value from the sensor is greater than the value selected in the dropdown (this is why I need to have it running as a background task)
3. The user can turn off the automation process by using killing the background task using an OFF button on the webpage.

I tried the following but I got `working outside of request context` error:

**web_plants.py**(which calls the python soil_on.py script):

```
@app.route("/threshold", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def threshold():
    tvalue= -1 #get value from dropdown
    msg = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
           msg= "rating above 3"
           os.system("python soil_on.py&")
    templateData = template(text = msg) #display text using template()
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
```

**soil_on.py**(which calls the `auto_Irrigation()` function from the `water` class:

```
import water

if __name__ == "__main__":
    water.auto_Irrigation()
```

**water.py** (which has `auto_Irrigation()`)

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def template(title = "HELLO!", text = ""):
templateDate = {
    'text' : text,
    'tvalues' : getTValues(),
    'selected_tvalue' : -1
}
return templateDate

def getTValues():
  return (10, 11, 15, 2, 1)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def auto_Irrigation():
    tvalue= -1 #get value from dropdown
   # msg = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        tvalue = int(request.form['tvalue'])
        if tvalue> 3:
            GPIO.output(40, GPIO.HIGH)
        else:
           GPIO.output(40, GPIO.LOW)
    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
```

**index.html**:

```
<h2> {{text}} </h2>
<form action= "{{ url_for('threshold') }}" method="POST">

     <select name= 'tvalue'>
      {% for tvalue in tvalues %}
        {% if selected_tvalue == tvalue %}
            <option value="{{ tvalue }}" selected='selected'>{{ tvalue }}</option>
        {% else %}
             <option value="{{ tvalue }}" >{{ tvalue }}</option>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      </select>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I am not sure of how to make the function as a background task. Currently this is working for me but the function is not running as a background task(so it only checks the value and turns on/off the pump):

**index.html**:

```
<h2> {{text}} </h2>
<form action= "{{ url_for('threshold') }}" method="POST">

     <select name= 'tvalue'>
      {% for tvalue in tvalues %}
        {% if selected_tvalue == tvalue %}
            <option value="{{ tvalue }}" selected='selected'>{{ tvalue }}</option>
        {% else %}
             <option value="{{ tvalue }}" >{{ tvalue }}</option>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      </select>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**web_plants.py:**(simplified the function `threshold()` for the sake of this post to make it more understandable)

```
def template(title = "HELLO!", text = ""):
    templateDate = {
        'text' : text,
        'tvalues' : getTValues(),
        'selected_tvalue' : -1
    }
    return templateDate

def getTValues():
    return (10, 11, 15, 2, 1) 

@app.route("/threshold", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def threshold():
    tvalue= -1 #default value
    msg = ''
    if request.method == "POST":            
        tvalue = int(request.form['tvalue'])
        if tvalue> 3:
            msg= "rating above 3"

    #generating template data
    templateData = template(text = msg)
    templateData['selected_tvalue'] = tvalue 

    return render_template('index.html', **templateData)
```

Comment: There are several ways to do it. I would first write all back-end functions to automate the process and stop the process using command-line options. Then create an interface for the user to control the same using HTTP. A good design is to keep backend and front end completely independent to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Celery which is an asynchronous task queue. You keep run your long running job, get status updates (even custom updates).

These links should help you understand how it works :

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flask-celery-example

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask

And you can even look at the Celery documentation.

This is example of how you can implement your function. You can take it forward from there.

/tasks.py

```
@celery.task
def my_task(self, threshold):
    if sensor_val < threshold:
        self.update_state(state="Sensor Value below threshold", meta={'sensor_val':sensor_val, 'threshold':threshold})
    else:
        self.update_state(state="Sensor Value past threshold. Please check.", meta={'sensor_val':sensor_val, 'threshold':threshold})
        """Do whatever you would like to do"""
```

/views.py

```
def sensor_check(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        threshold = request.POST['threshold']
        from tasks import my_task
        job = my_task.delay(threshold)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("task_status")+"?job_id="+job.id)

def task_status(request):
    if 'job_id' in request.GET:
        job_id = request.GET['job_id']
        job = AsyncResult(job_id)
        data = job._get_task_meta()
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        JsonResponse("No job ID given")
```

Comment: I thought `def my_task(self, threshold):`, `def sensor_check(request):` and `def task_status(request):` would be in the same python script but you placed them in two different ones `tasks.py` and `views.py`

Comment: @Tia I use celery with Django actually, never worked with Flask. But as per the post, you have to write everything in the app.py file itself. Just give all the functions I mentioned in 'views.py' a respective URL. sensor_check function will redirect to the URL for task_status which is a GET request and we pass the task id in the request which gives us task updates for that particular task.

Comment: However I am not sure if I can use Celery in my case as I don't know how I can stop the automation with it. I'll rather look into threads which can be easier to understand..

Comment: @Tia Write another function, if you press a button "kill automation", it goes to that function with the task_id, and you can call job.revoke(task_id, terminate=True)

Comment: I don't really have much time to look into Celery though, that's the prob as I need to get this done asap for the submission. Therefore, there is a high possibility it might not work as I need time to look into the functions.. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Request you to close the question then. @Tia